# How to navigate to the implementing methods instead of the class in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

First i'd like to thank everyone for your time. And also i'd like to make it clear up front that i've tried to google this, and i've also played with Android Studio for a few hours now, without any luck, so any help is greatly appreciated.

In Eclipse if you select one of the interface names (those one lists after the 'implements' keyword), the IDE will highlight all the methods within that class. It is particularly useful in Android when an Activity is implementing a few interfaces for dialog fragments.

i cannot find anything similar in Android Studio. The closest thing i found is "goto implementation(s)", which jump you to the class itself. While useful in other situation, "goto implementations" is completely useless here as it just navigate me back a few characters...

Comment: `Ctrl + [clicking on them]` maybe?

Comment: If you want this "exactly" behavior, you're out of luck.

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick responses! On the other hand Ctrl+[click] takes you to the interface declaration. And no i'm not that unreasonable to expect the exact behavior :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see the implemented methods in a class that implements one or more interfaces, place the caret at the implements keyword in the class declaration then press `Ctrl+Shift+F7`. A list of implemented interfaces shows up. Just select the interface whose methods you want to highlight, and press Enter.

To see the available mthods to implement, go to the class and press `Ctrl + O`. A window will appear showing the available methods based on the extended classes and implemented interfaces. Already implemented methods will not be shown.

You can search for any command by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + A`. After the box appear, just type what you want to do and a list of available actions will appear.

Comment: Thanks! Ctrl+Shift+F7 works almost the same as eclipse, but quite a bit awkwardly. Maybe i'm doing something wrong. First i did as regmoraes said, press Ctrl+Shift+F7 to choose one interface. But at this point all methods implementing all interfaces are still highlighed, i need to move away from the 'implements' keyword to let only the wanted methods to be highlighted. More strangely this procedure is accumulative. It takes a Ctrl+Shift+F7 and choose 'All listed' to clear the previous selections...

Answer (score 1):

'alt + command + B' on MAC, not sure about windows.

Comment: 'Ctrl+Alt+B' in windows / linux

Answer (score 0):

In windows, I think you can try `Ctrl-F12` then `Ctrl-I` or check at `Show Anonymous Classes`
Hope this help!

Comment: nope i tried that before, and no those are not anonymous classes

Answer (score 0):

The right way to navigate directly to the implementation class in `android studio` is to hover over the method and press `ctrl` + `alt` + `click`

Comment: No you misunderstood my question. The accepted answer is what i was looking for.